# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection when adding additional dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I had the following code:

```
 If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        ' If prospect is coming from unique url
        Dim prospect_url As String = Page.RouteData.Values("value")
        ' Save prospect_url into session variable
        Session("prospect_url") = prospect_url
        Using dbContext As IRFEntities = New IRFEntities
            ' Prepopulate the states dropdown.
            Dim getStates = (From p In dbContext.IRF_States _
                             Order By p.name _
                            Select p)
            ddlState.DataSource = getStates
            ddlState.DataTextField = "name"
            ddlState.DataValueField = "id"
            ddlState.DataBind()
            ' Grab info. about prospect based on unique url.
            Dim getProspect = (From p In dbContext.IRF_Prospects _
                              Where p.url = prospect_url _
                              Select p).FirstOrDefault
            ' If they have a record...
            If getProspect IsNot Nothing Then
                'If IsDBNull(getProspect.user_id) Then
                If getProspect.user_id Is Nothing Then
                    ' Prepopulate the form with their information.
                    ' These must have a value, so we need to make sure that no column is null in the database.
                    txtFirst.Text = getProspect.first_name
                    txtLast.Text = getProspect.last_name
                    txtAddress.Text = getProspect.address
                    txtCity.Text = getProspect.city
                    ddlState.SelectedValue = getProspect.state
                    txtZip.Text = getProspect.zip
                    txtPhone.Text = getProspect.phone
                    txtEmail.Text = getProspect.email_address
                    txtYearEnrolling.Text = getProspect.enrolling_in
                Else
                    ' Redirect them to login.
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
                End If
            End If
        End Using
    End If
```

I then added directly below ddlState.DataBind() the following:

```
  ' Prepopulate the programs dropdown.
             Dim getPrograms = (From p In dbContext.IRF_Program _
                              Order By p.name _
                             Select p)
            ddlProgram.DataSource = getPrograms
            ddlProgram.DataTextField = "name"
            ddlProgram.DataValueField = "id"
            ddlState.DataBind()
```

Now I get the error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

If I comment out the inserted code, the code works. Why is this code causing a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have lost this object:

`dbContext`

That is the resources (including the connection operations) for this object have already been disposed of and cleaned up.  You can re-create the object if you need to databind another drop down list.

```
Dim dbContext as IRFEntities=Nothing

 Using dbContext= New IRFEntities
   //perform first databind
 End Using

 Using dbContext = New IRFEntities
  //code to perform second databind
 End Using
```

Comment: How would I recreate the object?

Comment: You could also use the same type of object twice within two using statements (or try catch blocks) `Using dbContext As IRFEntities = New IRFEntities // more code... using dbContext2 AS IRFEntities = new IRFEntities //more code for ddlsites`

Comment: See my edit, you should only NEW the object once you are ready to use it.  That way you can declare it as a local variable, then `New` it when it is needed and re`new` it once it is needed again.

Comment: So, essentially, I'm creating two separate instances of the same object? dbContext and dbContext2?

Comment: @davemackey or just use the same one but renew it in another using statement - see my edit in my answer.